# jQuery.validate error message not formatting in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap

I have a registration form that is validated via jQuery Validate and while the form catches errors properly and displays the validation error message, **it doesn't use my "label label-important" class until I force the validation/click the submit button a SECOND time.**

Take a look here: http://jsbin.com/uguwem/12/

Here's my js code:

```
$('#registrationform').validate({ 
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents("div[class='control-group']").addClass("error");
        $(element.form).find("span[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass("label label-important");
        }, 
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
                $(element).parents(".error").removeClass("error"); 
        }, 
        errorElement: 'span' 
 });
```

Comment: please make sure your code does not produce any javascript errors. in bootstrp-button.js, firebug shows this error: $ is undefined
Line 67

Comment: place jquery-1.7.1.min.js before bootstrap-button.js to get rid of the error line 67.

Comment: I've done so - my site code is properly init-ed, I just pasted it in incorrectly.  That said, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `highlight` is called ***before*** the error element (a `span` in your case) is generated.

This means that when you try to find the `span` for the first time in `highlight`, it doesn't exist. `validate` doesn't remove error elements, it just shows and hides them, which is why it *is* found the second time the form is validated.

I would get around this by using the `errorPlacement` option instead and manually adding the class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#registrationform').validate({
        //errorClass: "label-important",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents("div[class='control-group']").addClass("error");

        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents(".error").removeClass("error");
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function($error, $element) {
            $error.addClass("label label-important").insertAfter($element);
        }
    });
});​
```

**Updated example:** http://jsbin.com/opoqan/

Comment: Error placement should be `$error.addClass("label label-important").appendTo($element.parents("div.controls"));`